# GET parameters CODEIGNITER error 404 Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

I'm sending this to codeigniter

http://ummus.co/pago/response.php?merchantId=506570&merchant_name=Grupo+Alto+Rio&merchant_address=Cra+28+%23+35+-+65+apto+401

And this is my code of controller

```
class Pago extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('file');
    }

    function index() {
    }

    function response() {
        //Respuesta por get al cliente
        $post = $this->m_data->get_all_get();
        if (!write_file('text.txt', json_encode($post))) {
            //echo 'Unable to write the file';
        } else {
            //echo 'File written!';
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason im getting 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found... Anybody knows about this?

Comment: Are you sure `response.php` is a valid URL in your CI app?

Comment: Your api isnt working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL seems wrong. Unless you've done some counter-productive routing, you should remove the .php extension from the controller method. So, this should work (at least there's no 404):

http://ummus.co/pago/response?merchantId=506570&merchant_name=Grupo+Alto+Rio&merchant_address=Cra+28+%23+35+-+65+apto+401

Learn about CodeIgniter URLs here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html